# Is it possible to use a string to call a file in raw in java?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create a string like

```
public String pos1="bloodstone";
```

And then use it in something like Mediaplayer as:

```
Mediaplayer s1;                                                                 
s1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pos1);
s1.start();
```

So if I modify `pos1="fireagate"` it will actually grab `R.raw.fireagate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getIdentifier()`:

```
String pos1 = "bloodstone";

int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(pos1, "raw", getPackageName());
Mediaplayer s1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawId);
```

This code snippet assumes that you are in a method on the activity — `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` are methods on `Context`, if your code resides somewhere outside of an activity.